# Centering with margin:auto does not work

Tags: html, css

I want to position my paragraph (title) into the middle of the div, but margin:auto; does absoulutely nothing.

```
#header {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
#title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px; 
  color: blue;
```

As you can see, both width and heights are defined, the paragraph does behave as a block element, so I really don't understand why is it still not centered in the middle of the div... Btw, the margin:auto did work for the divider, just not for the paragraph inside the divider.

Comment: Is that really how your CSS is? You are missing some brackets.

Comment: use dispaly:block instead of inline-block

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the supplied markup to show the problem is incomplete and the supplied CSS is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For center a Element using margin:
>
> 1)Define a width for element.
>
> 2)Element must be `block`.
>
> 3)Define `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`.

**So:**

Change:

```
display: inline-block;
```

To:

```
display:block;
```

Comment: Isnt inline-block suposed to preserve the properties of a block element? Why doesnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: inline-block;`, or explicitly set it to `display: block;`.

Comment: I just did, but the thing is, I am trying to have a paragraph lined up with a picture, and do that, the paragraph must be an inline element. How do preserve the two elements in line but still center the paragraph? Should I use more divs?

Answer (score 0):

"Margin:0 auto" is generally used for containers.

To align paragraph center, you can use styles for div.

```
text-align:center;
padding:10%;
```

For paragraph, remove display property and add these

```
line-height:50px;
height:50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align:center;` 
or you can also change

> `display:inline-block;`

to

> `display:block;`

Answer (score -2):

Put you paragraph in the div.

```
<div>
 <p>Something</p>
</div>
```

apply the following css to the paragraph

```
div{
     text align:centre;
  }

div.p{
 vertical-align:middle;

}
```